# Generate iOS static library using OpenGL ES 2.0 with cmake

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, cmake, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing a build toolchain for a multi-platform renderer (at least iOS/Mac for now). The project has a core library (the one that will be used by every platform targets), which should be compiled as a static library (.a) in order to be used in the other platform dependent project (like in an xcode project or eclipse for further android development).

This static library has dependencies on OpenGL ES 2.0 (iOS) or OpenGL for Mac. So I have the following file in order to include the correct headers:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_IOS
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
#endif

#ifdef PLATFORM_OSX
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#endif
```

The fact is that it is working perfectly for the Mac platform, the OpenGL headers are correctly found by cmake, but for iOS, it does not find OpenGLES; even when using a FindOpenGLES.cmake module that I have written, I am not able to find these headers, which seems logical since I don't even find them in /usr/include.

Comment: Try locating OpenGLES and ES2 directories. If they are present you can use include_directories() for the exact location.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was trying to do, but I don't know where they are located, I ran a `find /usr -name "*GLES*"` and nothing seems to be here.

Comment: 1. run a locate command. 2. or try find / -name `"*GLES*"` -type f -print  They must be somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You may need set the [CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH.html), the following is from my iOS came toolchain file

```
  set (IOS_SDK_ROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk")

  # Set the sysroot default to the most recent SDK
  set (CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT ${IOS_SDK_ROOT} CACHE PATH "Sysroot used for iOS support")

  # set the architecture for iOS - this env var sets armv6,armv7 and appears to be XCode's standard. The other found is ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS but that is armv7 only
  set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "${IOS_ARCH}" CACHE string "Build architecture for iOS")

  # set up the default search directories for frameworks
  set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH ${IOS_SDK_ROOT}/Developer/Library/Frameworks)
```